# How to create DataFrames with 9 and 14 elements random values comining from numbers, letters and special characters in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I need to create 2 DataFrame in Python Pandas:

1. DataFame with random 9-elements values (all combinations of numbers, letters and special characters) like below ("col1" as string data type) with 100 rows:

df1

```
col1
-----
123456789
1234M678x
_+3456P89
12345@78!
...
```

2. DataFame with random 14-elements values (all combinations of numbers, letters and special characters) like below ("col2" as string data type) with 100 rows:

df2

```
col2
--------------
92345678900554
123@^678900554
12345678PPl554
8 3456$89005x4
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.ascii_letters` , `string.punctuation` , `string.digits`.

---

```
import random
import string
import pandas as pd

ln = 9
rows = 100
df = pd.DataFrame([''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters  +
                                         string.punctuation + 
                                         string.digits) 
                           for _ in range(ln)) 
                   for _ in range(rows)],
                 columns = ['col1'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         col1
0   NKliCCsf8
1   BYyP`!%zN
2   35--pmn!<
3   6DRqa1ku/
4   XECuNst[b
..        ...
95  kA98&XZNk
96  ?Uo3J\3u4
97  =RHQW{I'z
98  L\R>RT|Y"
99  N'%&p{}Et
```

Comment: Where should I add ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters  + string.punctuation + string.digits) for _ in range(14)) in your code ?

Comment: @ratus111, You don't need, I send an example for explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
col1 = [secrets.token_urlsafe(9) for i in range(100)]
df1['col1'] = col1

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
col2 = [secrets.token_urlsafe(14) for i in range(100)]
df2['col2'] = col2
```

Comment: Lorenzo, I have error like: NameError: name 'secrets' is not defined, what can I do ?

Comment: you should import it first: 
`import secrets`

Comment: Hmm I see that your code generate random combinations of only letters and special characters, I do not see any only numbers like for example: 123456789 ?

Comment: `secrets.token_urlsafe()`generates random URL-safe text string, containing numbers, letters and url safe symbols. It may generate number only tokens but not necessarily

Comment: Is to possible to generate random values using your code but specify that, for example, 30% of these values are to be only numerical ?

Comment: well yes, you just need to use a combination of both:
`import string
import random
import secrets

numbers = string.digits
number_sequence = [secrets.choice(numbers) for i in range(3)]

letters = string.ascii_letters
letters_sequence = [secrets.choice(letters) for i in range(6)]

password = ''.join(random.sample(numbers+letters, 9))`